# Error handling with WebFlux Outbound Gateway in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-webflux

I'm trying to understand how errors should be handled in outbound gateway in spring webflux integration.

in spring integration **without** webflux **int-http:outbound-gateway** has **error-handler** like below:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
        http-method="GET"
        url-expression="url"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        error-handler="accessErrorHandler"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        />
```

but in spring integration **with** webflux int-webflux:outbound-gateway does not have error-handler

```
<int-webflux:outbound-gateway
                http-method="GET"
                url-expression="url"
                expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                header-mapper="headerMapper"
        />
```

this is my dependencies of pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Integration HTTP module is fully based on the `RestTemplate` from Spring Web. That one has the mentioned `ErrorHandler` for its *synchronous* requests.

The Spring Integration WebFlux module is fully based on the non-blocking `WebClient` from Spring WebFlux foundation. The logic internally is based on Project Reactor types, like `Flux` and `Mono`. To honor reactive streams specification, the `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler` just returns a `Mono` for response.
In case of some errors during interaction with the server we have this there:

```
requestSpec.exchange()
                    .flatMap(response -> {
                        HttpStatus httpStatus = response.statusCode();
                        if (httpStatus.isError()) {
                            return response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
                                    .reduce(DataBuffer::write)
                                    .map(dataBuffer -> {
                                        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                                        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                                        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                                        return bytes;
                                    })
                                    .defaultIfEmpty(new byte[0])
                                    .map(bodyBytes -> {
                                                throw new WebClientResponseException(
                                                        "ClientResponse has erroneous status code: "
                                                                + httpStatus.value() + " "
                                                                + httpStatus.getReasonPhrase(),
                                                        httpStatus.value(),
                                                        httpStatus.getReasonPhrase(),
                                                        response.headers().asHttpHeaders(),
                                                        bodyBytes,
                                                        response.headers().contentType()
                                                                .map(MimeType::getCharset)
                                                                .orElse(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                                            }
                                    );
                        }
                        else {
                            return Mono.just(response);
                        }
                    });
```

So, some `WebClientResponseException` is going to be thrown into a reply `Mono`.
In any reactive or non-reactive downstream, such an exception is going to be processed like this:

```
protected void sendErrorMessage(Message<?> requestMessage, Throwable ex) {
    Object errorChannel = resolveErrorChannel(requestMessage.getHeaders());
    Throwable result = ex;
    if (!(ex instanceof MessagingException)) {
        result = new MessageHandlingException(requestMessage, ex);
    }
    if (errorChannel == null) {
        logger.error("Async exception received and no 'errorChannel' header exists and no default "
                + "'errorChannel' found", result);
    }
    else {
        try {
            sendOutput(new ErrorMessage(result), errorChannel, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Exception exceptionToLog =
                    IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(requestMessage,
                            () -> "failed to send error message in the [" + this + ']', e);
            logger.error("Failed to send async reply", exceptionToLog);
        }
    }
}
```

Where that `errorChannel` is extracted from the headers of request message and falls back to the global `IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME`.

With all of that in hands you should subscribe to such a error channel to handle those 
`WebClientResponseException` instances respectively.
See more info about `RestTemplate` in Spring Framework docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-client-access